# Non-example of graded subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, graded-rings

I just want to check that I understand the definition of a graded subring, and I haven't seen anyone write down what seems like the most obvious type of non-example for a graded subring.

Inside of $k[x]$ with the standard grading, surely you can take $k[x^2]\subseteq k[x]$ as a (non-graded) subring, where in $k[x^2]$ you could choose to let $x^2$ be in degree $1$, in which case this is not a graded subring.

As a random aside, I guess one might like to think of $k[x^n]$ as being $k[z]$ but with $z$ in degree $n$. (not what I do above for the non-example of course)

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on what you mean by a "non-example." Another non-example of a graded subring is a banana. Presumably what you mean is an example of a subring which is not a graded subring.

In that case $k[x^2]$ does not work. With the grading inherited from $k[x]$, it is a graded subring. And changing the grading makes it not a subring at all (subrings inherit their grading from $k[x]$). Said another way, $k[x^2]$ with $x^2$ in degree $1$ admits a ring homomorphism to $k[x]$ but it is not a homomorphism of graded rings.

An example of a subring which is not a graded subring is $k[x^2 + x]$.

Comment: This is where my confusion lies. $k[x^2]\subseteq k[x]$ is indeed a subring, right, and I believe that if you were to give it the standard grading inherited from $k[x]$ then it gives you a graded ring which is isomorphic as graded rings to $k[z]$ where $z$ is in degree $2$. However, as rings, there is an isomorphism $k[x^2]\to k[y]$ for $y$ formal, and if I give $k[y]$ standard grading, I can endow $k[x^2]$ with graded ring structure where $x^2$ is now in degree $1$, so that $k[x^2]\subseteq k[x]$ as rings, and yet not as graded rings (standard grading on $k[x]$ but modified one on $k[x^2]$)

Comment: That's what I meant by 'surely you could choose $x^2$ to be degree 1' in the question statement and why I wrote 'take $k[x^2]\subseteq k[x]$ as a non-graded subring'. You take an actual subring, and then modify the grading of the subring so that it is different to the induced grading.

Comment: 'And changing the grading makes it not a subring at all' actually this I think is just false, so hopefully if you can clarify this, it will solve my confusion. The grading appears to me to be extrinsic, in the sense that it is just added structure, and I could take any subring inclusion and place lots of distinct gradings on them, some of which will give graded-subring inclusions, and others won't. Trivial example, unless I'm being silly, would be inclusion of a ring into itself. Like $R\subseteq R$ and you place whatever graded ring structures on left and right side as you want

Comment: I should be more careful about my 'trivial examples' at the end: namely not all rings can be given a non-trivial grading at all, but anyway, as long as you find a ring with at least one non-trivial grading, say $k[x]$ with trivial grading (everything graded in degree $0$) and a non-trivial grading $k[x]$ with $x$ in degree $1$, then the identity ring inclusion doesn't extend to a graded ring inclusion

Comment: @Calculus2022: this is to some extent a matter of convention, but: suppose I asked you to give an example of a subset of a group $G$ which is not a subgroup. Would you take a subset of the group, then modify the multiplication? No. What is meant by "not a subgroup" is that it isn't closed under the multiplication which is inherited from $G$. Of course you could arbitrarily modify the multiplication but then you aren't really talking about a subset of the group at all. Similarly, the way I would interpret "a subring of a graded ring which is not a graded subring" is that it is not graded...

Comment: ...with respect to the *induced* grading. Again, you could also pick some arbitrary other grading (or for that matter, some other arbitrary addition or multiplication) but then what is the point of regarding it as a subset of your graded ring in the first place?

Comment: Perhaps the disconnect here is that you use 'subring of a graded ring' to mean what I would call 'sub-graded-ring of a graded ring'. The difference being that my 'non-graded subring inclusions' aren't in the image of the forgetful functor from graded rings to rings. In particular my subrings really are genuine subrings, just not genuine graded-subrings. That is what I am asking about, really. Am I understanding correctly that a grading is a 'choice' of decomposition, and for example $k[x]$ has a choice of grading for each $n\in \Bbb N$, namely let $x$ be in degree $n$ (is this all of them?)?

Comment: "a subring of a graded ring which is not a graded subring"

Let $U:\text{Graded-Rings}\to \text{Rings}$ be the forgetful functor. I was asking about graded rings R,S for which there is a subring inclusion $U(R)\to U(S)$ which does not descend from an inclusion of graded rings $R\to S$, and just making sure that $k[x^2]$ really can be considered as a graded ring with $x^2$ in degree $1$, hence $U(k[(x^2)_1])\subseteq U(k[(x)_1])$ is a subring inclusion, but $k[(x^2)_1]\subseteq k[(x)_1]$ is not a graded-subring inclusion

Comment: Although admittedly, I only started using sub-graded-ring due to this comment thread, I will use that in future to be careful

Comment: @Calculus2002: no, that's not how I'm using "subring of a graded ring," e.g. $k[x^2 + x]$ is not a sub-graded-ring of $k[x]$, although it is a subring. Yes, a grading is a choice of decomposition and there are many such choices, and $k[x]$ has many other gradings other than the ones you describe, e.g. you could instead ask for $x + a$ to have degree $n$ for any scalar $a$. And yes, there's no issue with considering $k[x^2]$ as a graded ring with $x^2$ in degree $1$,but I would not call it a subring of $k[x]$ because the grading is not the induced grading. This last part is a convention.

Comment: Again, the term "non-example of a graded subring" is extremely ambiguous. Something can fail to be a graded subring in many ways. I think a good default interpretation is an example of a subring which fails to be a graded subring because it contains some elements but not their homogeneous components, and that's what the example of $k[x^2 + x]$ demonstrates.

Comment: Thank you, I believe I understand now. It is indeed more interesting to consider abstract-subrings of a graded-ring for which the subring cannot have the induced grading. If I suggested an edit to your answer to incorporate some of this comment content, I could accept it, and then delete all these comments?